# Drupalgap android app using quiz module

Tags: 7, quiz, javascript

I am trying to create a Drupal 7 quiz site of multiple choice questions. The users should be able to attempt quiz on the desktop site and as well as on an android app developed using [Drupalgap](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap) module. I have configured Drupalgap and quiz module correctly. I am able to output quiz as JSON in view but it does not have answer options in the body.

```
{  
    "nodes":[  
        {  
            "node":{  
                "title":"On which date United Nations (UN) Public Service Day is observed?",
                "Body":"On which date United Nations (UN) Public Service Day is observed?"
            }
        }
    ],
    "view":{  
        "name":"test",
        "display":"page",
        "path":"admin/structure/views/nojs/preview/test/page",
        "root":"nodes",
        "child":"node",
        "pages":1,
        "page":0,
        "count":1,
        "limit":10
    }
}
```

I am not sure that accessing and attempting quiz of the site from the android app is possible or not. Please guide me in this regard.